# CharacterController.velocity is always (0,0,0)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I copy pasted a character controller I had coded in the past, that uses `controller.velocity.sqrmagnitude == 0` to check if the player is standing still. Although in my previous project it worked flawlessly, it now doesn't. I did some debugging and found out that when I'm moving horizontally, the velocity is 0,0,0, but when I'm affected by gravity the y element of the vector works just fine. I'm so confused. Can anyone help me?

Edit: Here is the code. Basically I can't check if the Player is sprinting

```
using UnityEngine;

public enum PlayerMoveState {
    None, Walking, Sprinting, Crouching, Aiming
}

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    public CharacterController cc;
    public LayerMask ground;
    public Transform eye;

    [HideInInspector] public PlayerMoveState currentMoveState;
    [HideInInspector] public bool onAir;

    [Space]
    [Header("Movement Settings")]
    public float moveSpeed;
    [Range(1f, 2f)] public float sprintMultiplier;
    [Range(0f, 1f)] public float airMultiplier;
    [Range(0f, 1f)] public float crouchMultiplier;
    [Range(0f, 1f)] public float aimMultiplier;
    public float crouchTransition;
    public float jumpHeight;
    public float gravity = -9.81f;

    [Space]
    [Header("Keybinds")]
    public KeyCode sprintKey = KeyCode.LeftShift;
    public KeyCode crouchKey = KeyCode.LeftControl;
    public KeyCode jumpKey = KeyCode.Space;

    Vector2 inputVector;
    Vector3 velocity;
    
    void FixedUpdate() {
        inputVector = inputVector.normalized * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        Vector3 moveDir = transform.forward * inputVector.y + transform.right * inputVector.x;
   
        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        if (!onAir && velocity.y < 0) velocity.y = -5f;

        cc.Move(moveDir);
        cc.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    PlayerMoveState DetermineMoveState() {
        if (Input.GetKey(crouchKey)) return PlayerMoveState.Crouching;

        if (cc.velocity.sqrMagnitude == 0f) return PlayerMoveState.None;

        if (Input.GetKey(sprintKey)) return PlayerMoveState.Sprinting;

        return PlayerMoveState.Walking;
    }
}
```

Comment: as your controller code isnt here, im going to guess you arent moving using physics

Comment: @BugFinder I use controller.Move() for both the moveDir and the gravity. Do you want me to upload the whole script?

Comment: As its not your first post you should be capable of [mcve]

Comment: @BugFinder I've edited the post. I believe that there all the parts that the problem might be located.

Comment: ok so, your controller should not be the owner of velocity, surely physics owns physics, and has a velocity.. however, you only ever set velocity.y so of course if its not falling it will have a velocity of 0,0,0 ..   it seems odd you are manually doing gravity...

Comment: I would think you'd need to use `Update`, since everything is working on `Time.deltaTime`, and because it isn't using the physics engine.  There is a random fixedDeltaTime in there too..

Comment: @BugFinder no, this is actually how you use a [`CharacterController`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html) - it doesn't have a `velocity` on its own (like a Rigidbody would) but you are responsible for calculating the velocity to be applied yourself. In OP's code that could basically be a simple `float` though since as you say `y` is the only axis ever updated on it - but to be fair Unity's example is also dumb in that regard :D. Note though that OP is passing in the move input accordingly in `cc.Move(moveDir);` which is valid that way

Comment: @hijinxbassist within `FixedUpdate` both `fixedDeltaTime` and [`deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) return the same value => It is actually recommended to use `deltaTime` everywhere

Comment: OP, where do you call `DetermineMoveState`? As @hijinxbassist says it might indeed happen that - since you only move in `FixedUpdate` intervals - the velocity is `0, 0, 0` in all other frames  => move your movement into `Update` ... in general you should **NOT** use `==` for float values though ... rather use [`cc.velocity == Vectior3.zero`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_eq.html) which uses an approximated precision of `0.00001`

Comment: @derHugo I call the DetermineMoveState function inside the update function. This Character Controller script is an expanded version of Brackeys' First Person Controller. I coded it about 2 months ago. In my previous project it worked just fine. I literally just copy pasted it to a knew project and the sprint is broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! For anyone wandering calling `cc.Move()` twice causes some weird behavior. Only the second move function determines the velocity and that is why the vector showed the velocity on the y-axis. The solution is simple:

1. Change the order of the 2 move function (NOTE: By doing this you won't be able to get the velocity of the player applied by `cc.Move(velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime)`. In my case it worked perfectly, because later on I added a speedometer and didn't care about measuring the gravity, but keep that in mind).

**OR**

2. Merge the two vectors and add them together: `cc.Move(mergedVector)`